# A superset of an unbounded set is unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose S and T are subsets of the reals, $\Bbb R$. And that S is a subset of T. Prove that if S is not bounded, then T is not bounded.

Comment: What is your approach to this problem? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: now already match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Prove the contrapositive: If $T$ is bounded, then its subset $S$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks! This was the hint I needed.